# Issue in ArrayList in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

In my app I am using `ArrayList` to save `string` values.These values are taken from `AsyncTask` and these values are to be set to a `TextView` in adapter.But it only set values from second position in that `ArrayList`.In the Log it is showing that `ArrayList` values it contains all values.But while setting it not display first value.Code mentioned below.

```
indexOfSelectedId = photoall_id.indexOf(photoid_c);

for (int i = indexOfSelectedId ; i < photoall_id.size(); i++) {
    all_postid.add(photoall_id.get(i));
    url = URLS.BASEURL + "mobile_api.php?action=post&post_id=" + photoall_id.get(i) + "&access_token=" + accesstoken + "&user_id=" + userid;

    new GetImage().execute(url);


}

for (int i = 0; i < indexOfSelectedId; i++) {

    all_postid.add(photoall_id.get(i));
    url = URLS.BASEURL + "mobile_api.php?action=post&post_id=" + photoall_id.get(i) + "&access_token=" + accesstoken + "&user_id=" + userid;


    new GetImage().execute(url);


}


adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter ();

viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

private class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

String json = null;
ArrayList<String> all_data;
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    all_data=new ArrayList<>();

    showProgress("Loading Images....");
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> aVoid) {

    //   touchImageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
  dismissProgress();





    all_url.add(aVoid.get(0));

    all_cap.add(aVoid.get(1));




}

@Override
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {

    JSONReader reader = new JSONReader();
    json = reader.getJsonGET(params[0]);

    if (json != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
            if (object.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(0).getInt("count") != 0) {

                photo_url = object.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(0).getString("photo_url");

               photo_caption = object.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(0).getString("photo_caption");


            }
            all_data.add(photo_url);
            all_data.add(photo_caption);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return all_data;
}
```

}

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    ImageView imageView;

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return all_url.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Context context = FullScreenActivity.this;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, container,
            false);



    imageView = (ImageView)viewLayout. findViewById(R.id.cardImage);

    int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.dimen.padding_medium);
    imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

    Log.d("caption for testingggggggggfgfgf", all_upuser.get(position));
    Picasso.with(context).load(all_url.get(position)).into(imageView);
    current_postid=all_postid.get(position);




        String temp_cap=all_cap.get(position);

        image_head.setText(temp_cap);




    ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout, 0);

    return viewLayout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);

}
```

}

And the log is

```
     clickzy D/caption for testing﹕ good morning
01-27 12:34:05.200    3389-3389/com.wat.clickzy W/Settings﹕ Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
01-27 12:34:05.210    3389-3389/com.wat.clickzy D/caption for testing﹕ lol
                                            caption for testing﹕ vv
01-27 12:34:06.780    3389-4782/com.wat.clickzy D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 806K, 9% free 29169K/31980K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
01-27 12:34:06.780    3389-4782/com.wat.clickzy I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 31.335MB for 1728016-byte allocation
01-27 12:34:06.805    3389-4782/com.wat.clickzy D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 9% free 30855K/33668K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
01-27 12:34:08.525    3389-3389/com.wat.clickzy D/caption for testingggggggggfgfgf﹕ red
01-27 12:34:08.590    3389-4796/com.wat.clickzy D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 851K, 9% free 30850K/33668K, paused 46ms, total 46ms
01-27 12:34:08.590    3389-4796/com.wat.clickzy I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 32.976MB for 1728016-byte allocation
01-27 12:34:08.630    3389-3400/com.wat.clickzy D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 32537K/35356K, paused 43ms, total 43ms
01-27 12:34:10.060    3389-3389/com.wat.clickzy D/caption for testingggggggggfgfgf﹕ gleegy.
```

`Log` contains first value "goodmorning",but it set to `Textview` from second value.Please suggest me any solution

Comment: What is the problem for negative marking

Comment: Please help me to find it.

Comment: Are you using Picasso library?

Comment: yes, used for loading images

Comment: This log is just a warning. You have nothing to do with it

Comment: Post your full code.Otherwise no one can help you

Comment: Actually the issue happens in this locaton

Comment: @Jas Question updated

Comment: You don't need an AsyncTask if you use Picasso

Comment: AsyncTask for getting values from server

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you are doing, but it's hard to tell without seeing what `JSONReader` is doing

Comment: No issue in JSONReader all_caps arraylist contains all data. allcaps.get(0) contains first value in adapter class.It takes only from second value while it set to a TextView.     image_head.setText(temp_cap);

Comment: Anybody please help me

Comment: First two values retrieve while calling from arraylist at position=0

Comment: Check the positions of your array items

Comment: positiions are 0 and 1.

Comment: I can't solve the issue.